# Packing RAW AAC into m4a container?

Tags: android, encoding, java-native-interface, aac, m4a

I have an Android app using FAAC to convert raw PCM into raw AAC, but now I don't know how it can be packed into m4a container.

I've searched on the net and found a lot of info, but none of them solves my question. Most of them referring ffmpeg / mp4box command line, but what I need is to solve this in Android environment, which means either Java Eclipse, or JNI.

Any hint please?

Comment: did u get any solution? dont hesitate to share it please..

Comment: 5 years later, same problem. Could you solve it back then?

Comment: @muetzenflo Hey have you solved you problem would like to help you out.

Comment: @TheCuriousDev Thanks for the link, will have a look at it!

Answer (score 0):

This [AACEncoder Project on Github](https://github.com/timsu/android-aac-enc/) seems to be great! 
And it works for me.

It actually has the ability **encode raw PCM wave file into AAC raw file** and then **repack that raw AAC file into MP4(M4A) container**.

So if you are just looking to convert raw AAC into M4A, [this class](https://github.com/timsu/android-aac-enc/blob/master/src/com/todoroo/aacenc/AACToM4A.java) will be a good start and dont forget to add its dependencies.

But its definitely a good choice for someone who wants do it without FFMPEG and NDK.

Answer (score -2):

NOTE: OOPS REALLY SORRY, DIDNT SEE YOU NEEDED AN ANDROID ENVIRONEMENT ONLY SOLUTION. HOWEVER I KEEP MY ANSWER SINCE IT MIGHT BE HELPFUL FOR SOME OTHERS.

I had same problem, not android related but same Raw AAC problem, and i found the answer on this forum. Now my Rockboxed portable player can read AAC audio tracks extracted from FLV YouTube videos.
However i don't know the hell how to batch convert. I'm not that much command line saavy.

in ffmpeg:
ffmpeg -i input.aac -codec: copy output.m4a

in MP4Box:
MP4Box -add input.aac#audio output.m4a

PS: you'll probably have to rename your files, ie. MJBeatiT.aac rather than Michael Jackson - Beat It (remix2013).aac