# Programmatically convert M4A to MP3

Tags: vb.net, mp3, m4a

I want to create a tool where you can enter a lot of `.m4a` files, then it converts them to `.mp3` and sorts them by `id3` tags.

The code for sorting is already complete and works really well but I can't find sample code that converts `.m4a` to `.mp3`.

Anyone have some nice snippet/link/hint I can use?

Comment: You can search stackoverflow for examples, such as [one with nearly an identical title](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/70096/how-do-i-programmatically-convert-mp3-to-an-itunes-playable-aac-m4a-file)

Comment: @BryanH: that's ruby. [Here is an answer for .NET](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/144466/how-do-i-convert-an-m4a-file-to-an-mp3-or-wma-file-programmatically) (though it's C#, should be very similar).